# Blueprint CSS boxes

Tags: css, padding, blueprint-css

I am currently testing out [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) to create the layout for a site. So far it has been going great, but now I've run into a problem I'm wondering if there is any elegant solution to.

I am using the default 24 column layout and have a situation where I would like to do something similar to:

```
<div class="span-8 box">..</div>
<div class="span-8 box">..</div>
<div class="span-8 box last">..</div>
```

Problem is that the box-class adds a padding which causes the three div's to not fit into the 24 columns.
One "solution" is to use span-7 instead for all three, but this doesn't fill the entire width.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not everyone knows what Blueprint is, some links to a live example of your problem and the Blueprint website would help us a lot :)

Comment: True. Unfortunately I'm sitting at a cafe right now, so I can't put it online for anyone to see. What I meant by an elegant solution though is one that uses the capabilities of the Blueprint CSS framework.

Comment: Well you can use a site like jsFiddle to put up a temporary example for us to see :)

Comment: Ah cool, didn't know that site.
I put it up here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pDfGE/

As you can see, the three boxes doesn't fit inside the total width of 24 columns

Comment: I See, I'll see if I can come up with a solution for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class this way:

```
<div class="span-8">
    <div class="box">..</div>
</div>
<div class="span-8">
    <div class="box">..</div>
</div>
<div class="span-8 last">
    <div class="box">..</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the "span-7" css rule:

```
...
.span-7 {width:274px;}
...
```

And change the divs to "span 7".

Simplest thing I could think of :)

[jsFiddle example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/HWG4e/).

Comment: I know that is one solution, but it's really not what I want. I dont want to change anything from the Blueprint framework if I can avoid it.